# Error installing plugin Google Cloud Tools for eclipse 1.8.4 (ubuntu)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

When I try to install the app engine plugin from the Eclipse marketplace, the installation fails returning:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=_home_user_eclipse_jee-2021-063_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for -9147676190077153272.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for -9147676190077153272.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8122282445186051625.
OK
```

Environment:
Ubuntu 18.04.6
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 2021-06 (4.20.0)
Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.8.4
Java JDK 8

Any hint?

Thanks in advance,
Sebas

Already tried using the "help-install new software" option.
Same result with ubuntu 20 or JDK 11.
I tried to find previous plugin versions with no result.

Comment: The same error appears installing the google plugin in Elipse 2021-09 for windows.
Any way to access older builds of the "Google cloud tools" plugin?